# How to run a Go binary in a debugger while passing arguments?

Tags: debugging, go

I have a precompiled Go binary called abc which I run like this `./abc import --src_type=redis --src_uri="redis://localhost:6379/0" redis-test`

I also want to print a few values in certain packages of this application for debugging purposes. How do I run this binary with the arguments in a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume dlv is already installed?  If not, it's a simple go get, see https://github.com/derekparker/delve

```
dlv exec ./abc -- import --src_type=redis --src_uri="redis://localhost:6379/0" redis-test
```

-- in the debugger means take the rest as arguments to the program being run